# Errors while setting up a Kafka connector pipeline

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

### Errors while setting up a Kafka connector pipeline

#### Enviroment overview:

Docker containers

1. docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypw -d mysql:latest
2. docker run -d --name *Elasticsearch* -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" *Elasticsearch*: 7.9.2

Operating System

1. WSL2 ON - Windows-10 Version 1909 (OS build 18363.1139)

Kafka Version

1. confluent-6.0.0

Hello
I’m reading Kafka: The Definitive Guide by Neha Narkhede, Gwen Shapira, and Todd Palino
I’ve reached the *Connector Example: MySQL to Elasticsearch* chapter (p.146) and i'm
following the instructions to create a pipeline from a MySql source to a *Elasticsearch* sink.
I have made some diversions from the instructions

- I created the mysql and *Elasticsearch* connectors using mvn package instead of mvn build
- I placed the said connectors in a folder named C:\Users\ROY\confluent-6.0.0\share\kafka
  tougher with some other connectors I’ve downloaded. I set the plugin.path vaiable in connect-distributed.properties to:
  plugin.path=C://Users//ROY//confluent-6.0.0//share//kafka,/mnt/c/Users/ROY/confluent-6.0.0/share/kafka
- I'm using *mysql* and *Elasticsearch* as docker containers.

The mysql connector works fine and reads data into a topic,
but when I try to create the *Elasticsearch* connector I get the following error:

```
...
(io.confluent.connect._Elasticsearch_._Elasticsearch_SinkConnectorConfig:354)
[2020-10-16 12:22:27,170] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elastic-login-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:187)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/searchbox/action/Action
    at io.confluent.connect._Elasticsearch_._Elasticsearch_SinkTask.start(_Elasticsearch_SinkTask.java:74)
    at io.confluent.connect._Elasticsearch_._Elasticsearch_SinkTask.start(_Elasticsearch_SinkTask.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:302)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.searchbox.action.Action
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 11 more
...
```

Can someone assist resolving the issue and give and explanation to the error?

Thank you

Roy

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. After I ran 'mvn package' on the elastic search connector source code I should have copied a whole directory into Kafka's /share dir, instead I only took one .jar file.